# C++ object referencing/accessing

Tags: c++, pointers, object, reference

Ok so I have a GroupDB class (Group Databse) and nested inside I have a Group Class. The Group class contains two private variables containing the group's name and the group's members. Every time the user creates a new group, a group object gets created and added to a vector of group objects inside of my GroupDB class. I'm working on a function that lets user's join a specific group...

**I'm trying to iterate through this vector of Group objects and access each one until I find the correct group, then I would like to add the user to the correct groups vector of group members.**

Here's the relevant code:

```
void GroupDB::JoinGroup(string n, string t) {
        for (vector<Group>::iterator i = groupList.begin();
            i != groupList.end(); ++i)
        {
            Group g = *i;
            string x = g.GetName();
            if (x == t)
                i.Join(n, t);
        }
}
```

I'm trying to understand how the iterator works.
**I believe the `Group g = *i; string x = g.GetName();` is correct, but how do I actually call the `Join()` function for the group object inside groupList?**

Heres my Class headers as well:

```
class GroupDB {
public:
    void JoinGroup(string, string);

private:
    class Group
    {
    public:
        string GetName();
        vector<string> GetMembers();
        void Join(string, string);
        Group(string);

    private:
        string name;
        vector<string> members;
    };

private:
    vector<Group> groupList;
};
```

Comment: Could you please [elaborate about your actual errors](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26069907/edit) a bit more please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a couple of ways.

You can either dereference the iterator to access the object (and there is no need to copy it before checking the name):

```
{
    string x = i->GetName();  // The same as (*i).GetName()
    if (x == t)
        i->Join(n, t);    // The same as (*i).Join(n, t)
}
```

or you can use a reference variable in order to introduce a new name for the object in the vector without copying it:

```
{
    Group& g = *i;
    string x = g.GetName();
    if (x == t)
        g.Join(n, t);
}
```

Comment: Ah this just made it all click in my head. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

In this line `i.Join(n, t);` you actually try to call the function `Join()` of the `vector<Group>::iterator` object. To get the wished behaviour you have to dereference your iterator first so you call the function of the `Group` object. This is how it should look like `(*i).Join(n, t);`. Note that `*i.Join(n, t);` won't work.